Why are requests not being sent inside the docker container?
There is a rented server on reg.ru where the app is running. There is a need to send network requests. There was a problem with sending them inside the docker container.
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11.7
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libpq-dev postgresql-client build-essential libpq-de>
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /backend

COPY . .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r req.txt
CMD  daphne  -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 backend.asgi:application

I have prepared a small function for the tests (requests==2.30.0)
import requests


def get_data(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
        print(url, 'good')
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout as e:
        print(url, '------fiasko bratan-------', e)


urls = ['https://google.com', 'https://staminity.com', 'https://fatsecret.com']

for i in urls:
    get_data(i)

Requests are successfully sent on the server.
However, when used inside the container, it throws a timeout error.
Among the tested sites, 1 passed 2 no.
https://google.com good
https://staminity.com ------fiasko bratan------- HTTPSConnectionPool(host='staminity.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
https://fatsecret.com ------fiasko bratan------- HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fatsecret.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)


Also, I tried ping inside the container:
PING google.com (173.194.222.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lo-in-f102.1e100.net (173.194.222.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=107 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from lo-in-f102.1e100.net (173.194.222.102): icmp_seq=2 ttl=107 time=15.9 ms

PING staminity.com (81.163.31.117) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wealthkingusa.com (81.163.31.117): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=1.10 ms
64 bytes from wealthkingusa.com (81.163.31.117): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=1.25 ms

ING fatsecret.com (52.206.184.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- fatsecret.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 306

Starting app in docker-compose
version: "3.3"

services:
  backend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"

    volumes:
      - ./data/static:/var/www/static
      - ./data/media:/var/www/media
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"

    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    volumes:
      - ./data/media:/var/www/media
      - ./data/static:/var/www/static
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./data/nginx_logs:/var/log/nginx
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"

    depends_on:
      - backend

    links:
      - backend

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot

  database:
    image: postgres:15.5-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file: ./postgresql-db/.pg-env
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"

  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.5-alpine
    hostname: redis
    volumes:
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"

  celery-worker:
    build:
      context: ./backend

    hostname: worker
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A backend.celery worker  --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"

    links:
      - redis

    depends_on:
      - redis

  celery-beat:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    hostname: beat
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A backend beat -l debug
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"

    depends_on:
      - redis
      - celery-worker
      - database
      - backend

    links:
      - redis
      - celery-worker

  celery-flower:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    restart: always
    hostname: flower
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A backend flower
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"

    links:
      - database
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis

As a result, all requests are executed successfully, except for the docker container
Also, strangely, pip cannot connect to the Internet inside the container either...
root@****:/home/saligin/deploy# docker-compose exec backend bash
root@****:/backend# pip install python-docx
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/python-docx/

I do not know if I need to configure docker additionally for internet access

The last step of your Dockerfile is  pip install but there's no command thereafter to run  a process (ENTRYPOINT or CMD)

lasе entry CMD  daphne  -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 backend.asgi:application

Please edit your question to include that line. How are you running the container?

thanks. I edited the question and added how the app is launched

you can't ping the last one - so while thats possible and https should still work - its definitely possible that the host you are using has been blackholed that you cant reach it..  Second, the host could throttle your outgoing requests so reaching it could be problem with the host itself.. Only thing that one could suggest is to increase the timeout and see if that has any effect..

everything works on the host, outside the container. It does not work only inside the container. How can I test your theory?
